# Compute Shortest Distance(s) between two points

Tags: mapinfo, bing-maps

I am using Mapinfo 11. I want user to be able to find shortest route between two points so that user can travel from point A to point B using these path. Any Idea how to achieve this?

Edit: I need to be able to do this with the Bing Hybrid Map.

Comment: pls give some detail, Do you use MapInfo®
Routing J Server thing or only mapinfo?

Comment: @Aragon we use only mapinfo. do we need additional resources?

Comment: I have tool for route calculation in mapinfo which shows the route b/w two location, that is mapbasic program if u are interested than gives me ur requirement in detail like which kind of input u provide for route calculation.

Answer (score 1):

apparently there is a tool that allows you to do that in mapinfo

http://www.kxcad.net/mapinfo/mapinfo_professional/mapinfow-37-10.html

Comment: need to calculate distance in bing hybrid map it doesn't support that

Comment: it's true.. I have never worked with this type of operations with Bing Hybrid Maps.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Distance Calculator which located in Tool Manager, but if you are interested professional tool, i advice you MapInfo® Routing J Server.

For Distance Calculater :

```
Tools > Tool Manager > Distance Calculator
```

Description of tool:

> This program calculates the distance form all the objects in one table
>   to all objects in a second table or itself. It then returns the
>   closest or farthest distance(s).

and you can also try RouteWare RouteFinder for MapInfo tool [here](http://www.routeware.dk/download.php)...

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Distance Calculator does not work with bing hybrid map I need to calculate distance in this map and highlight the path

Comment: Bing Map is just a "stupid" background raster. You can't use it for any calculations (route or anything else). Which area of the world is it you are working in?

Comment: @UffeKousgaard I am working with south asia - Nepal

Comment: You need a different source of data, such as OpenStreetMap for your routing. If you translate it into TAB format, then you can use RouteFinder as suggested for the routing.

Answer (score 0):

calculating the shortest distance , there is a logic behind it.

When we ask the bing or google service to give a shortest distance betwen point A to point B , it gives us the route which is drivable , if there a one way from B to A which is short , it wont give that route.

So how you have to proceed it

1. Calculate the route and distance from Point A to B
2. Calculate the route and distance from Point B to A.

take the Route which has shortest distance.